# Custom delivery-tag rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq

I want to receive streaming replies from RabbitMQ based on the publisher model. It's the only way I see that I can stream replies without having to use RPC.

So I went ahead and tried to use the ack delivery-tag as the identifier of the item I just processed. But that gave me an error that such a delivery-tag does not exist. So, is it possible to manually set the delivery tag when sending a message to RabbitMQ?

If not, is there another to achieve streaming updates/acknowledgements from consumer to producer without using rpc?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the `delivery-tag` sent by RabbitMQ in order to ack a message, otherwise you will get an error.

If you need to have a particular ID per message, and that ID is to be defined by the application, then you could set the `correlation-id` header.